# Macbook Retina Display Scalling- Web Browsers

Tags: macbook

I've done the regular scaling from the display settings and the icons and desktop are adequately scaled but the text in the web browsers are still not on the adjusted scale, making everything in the browser extremely small.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this from the [ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Browsers) (which might be a bit outdated):

> ### Firefox
>
> Open Firefox advanced preferences page (`about:config`) and set
>   parameter `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` to `2` (or find the one that suits
>   you better; 2 is a good choice for Retina screens).
>
> If you use a HiDPI monitor such as Retina display together with
>   another monitor, you can use [AutoHiDPI](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autohidpi/) add-on in order to
>   automatically adjust `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` setting for the active
>   screen.
>
> From Firefox version 38 onwards, your system (GTK+ 3.10) settings
>   should be taken into account.[[1]](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=975919)
>
> ### Chromium / Google Chrome
>
> *stuff about ArchLinux packages* ...try setting default page zoom level to 200% (although it is
>   not the most elegant solution).
>
> Additionally, using current Chrome packages from AUR, and possibly
>   chromium packages as well (not tested) the browser can be launched
>   with the command line flag `--force-device-scale-factor` and a scaling
>   value. This will scale all content and ui, including tab and font
>   size. For example:
>
> ```
> google-chrome --force-device-scale-factor=2
> ```
>
> Using this option, a scaling factor of `1` would be normal scaling.
>   Floating point values can be used. Note that this currently *(as of
>   chrome 39)* breaks the UI somewhat in terms of menus and forms. A bug
>   report has been filed for the [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=400837).
>
> ### Opera
>
> Since version 24 one can alter Opera's DPI by starting it with the
>   `--alt-high-dpi-setting=X` command line option, where X is the desired DPI. For example, with `--alt-high-dpi-setting=144` Opera will assume
>   that DPI is 144. Newer versions of opera will auto detect the DPI
>   using the font DPI setting (in KDE: the force font DPI setting.)
>
> Generally speaking, Opera's HiDPI support is excellent. Since it is
>   also built using Chrome's blink renderer, and has an extension which
>   runs most Chrome extensions, it's a very viable alternative to Chrome
>   with much better HiDPI support.

Comment: Works well on Firefox, but the text is still small only in the address bar. The Chrome didn't work and I don't use Opera. Thanks! I may just set the resolution down a bit. The text will look a little fuzzy but it will be consistent. Do you maybe know how to change the font size throughout the operating system?

Comment: For font sizes I know in GNOME 3 this is possible via a 'Tweak Tool' - for Unity try 'Appearance' settings, 'Ubuntu Tweak' or 'Unity Tweak Tool'.